Resizing animated nav toggler
I am creating an animated html, css and jacavaript nav toggler for a therapy website which I have finally got working on all devices-but I am having trouble making it smaller without affecting the alignment of the cross after activating the toggler. This is my code:
  <!Doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-5.3.3 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css">
    
    <!-- Latest jQuery library for plugins that require it-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    
    
    /*=========================Header========================*/
    /*Navbar*/
    .navbar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    }
   
    
    /*hero banner*/
    .hero-image{
    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 267px;
    background-color:green;
    
    /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    }
    
    /* Place text in the middle of the image */
    .hero-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    }
    
    /*Hamburger toggler*/
    
   
     button {
         cursor: pointer;
         background: none;
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         appearance: none;
    }
    
     .btns {
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         justify-content: center;
    }
     .btns_item {
         margin: 0 20px;
         text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------ * #02 * ------------------------------------------------------------ */
     .btnMenu02 {
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         background-color: #000;
    }
     .btnMenu02 > span {
         display: block;
         transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
     .btnMenu02 > span > span, .btnMenu02 > span::before, .btnMenu02 > span::after {
         display: block;
         width: 70%;
         height: 8px;
         margin: 12px auto;
         content: '';
         background-color: #fff;
         border-radius: 4px;
         transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
     .btnMenu02.is-open > span {
         transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
     .btnMenu02.is-open > span > span {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     .btnMenu02.is-open > span::before {
         transform: translateY(20px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
     .btnMenu02.is-open > span::after {
         transform: translateY(-20px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    
    /*//Hamburger toggler*/
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <header>
    <div class="hero-image">
    <img class="hero-image" src="assets/images/banner.png" alt="">
    
    <div class="hero-text">
    <h2 style="font-size: 20px">Natural Therapist</h2>
    <button>Hire me</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--Nav-->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler btnMenu02 js-btnMenu" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    
    
    <span><span></span></span>
   
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarToggler">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!--/Nav-->
    
    </header>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    
    $(function() {
      $('.js-btnMenu').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
      });
    });
    
    </script>
    
    <!--//Header
    ==================================-->
    
    <!-- javascript (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!--personal javascripts-->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>

Basically, I am wanting this hamburger toggler to be of a smaller size suitable for a website or mobile. After much research and modifying the codes, I just find that altering the width and height of the .btnMenu02 abd changing the height of the span linesof the     .btnMenu02 > span > span, .btnMenu02 > span::before, .btnMenu02 > span::after makes the cross icon kind of wonky and out of alignment.
Is there a trick to resizing this toggler and making it smaller without affecting the alignment of the cross icon?

I think what you are looking for is zoom  (or scale): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

If you could provide screenshots of how it looks after you've attempted, that would help.
However, I have changed the following with some success:
.btnMenu02 {
         width: 50px;
         height: 50px;
         background-color: #000;
    }
  .btnMenu02 > span > span, .btnMenu02 > span::before, .btnMenu02 > span::after {
         display: block;
         width: 90%;
         height: 4px;
         margin: 6px auto;
         content: '';
         background-color: #fff;
         border-radius: 4px;
         transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

The key points that affected the weird look after resize was the margin: 12px auto; as this affected the lines escaping the box.
Also, since it was made smaller, the lines were too short in width so increasing it to 90% made it feel more in place.
I think to achieve whatever size you're after, you should adjust the value of the height and margin in proportion to your width and height of the background.
Full example:


 <!Doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-5.3.3 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css">
    
    <!-- Latest jQuery library for plugins that require it-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    
    
    /*=========================Header========================*/
    /*Navbar*/
    .navbar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    }
   
    
    /*hero banner*/
    .hero-image{
    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 267px;
    background-color:green;
    
    /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    }
    
    /* Place text in the middle of the image */
    .hero-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    }
    
    /*Hamburger toggler*/
    
   
     button {
         cursor: pointer;
         background: none;
         border: none;
         outline: none;
         appearance: none;
    }
    
     .btns {
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         justify-content: center;
    }
     .btns_item {
         margin: 0 20px;
         text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------ * #02 * ------------------------------------------------------------ */
     .btnMenu02 {
         width: 50px;
         height: 50px;
         background-color: #000;
    }
     .btnMenu02 > span {
         display: block;
         transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
     .btnMenu02 > span > span, .btnMenu02 > span::before, .btnMenu02 > span::after {
         display: block;
         width: 90%;
         height: 4px;
         margin: 6px auto;
         content: '';
         background-color: #fff;
         border-radius: 4px;
         transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
     .btnMenu02.is-open > span {
         transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
     .btnMenu02.is-open > span > span {
         opacity: 0;
    }
     .btnMenu02.is-open > span::before {
         transform: translateY(20px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
     .btnMenu02.is-open > span::after {
         transform: translateY(-20px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    
    /*//Hamburger toggler*/
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <header>
    <div class="hero-image">
    <img class="hero-image" src="assets/images/banner.png" alt="">
    
    <div class="hero-text">
    <h2 style="font-size: 20px">Natural Therapist</h2>
    <button>Hire me</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--Nav-->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler btnMenu02 js-btnMenu" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    
    
    <span><span></span></span>
   
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarToggler">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a clas




Hello Jacques, Thank you for your comments and code, Thats very true, it does seem to be a thing of spacing. I tried the code you provided and it helped loads to get the right sizes. However, the alignmet was still a bit wonky. But like you say, it is the sizing affecting the positioning. Turns out it was the translateY values for the  .btnMenu02.is-open > span::before and  .btnMenu02.is-open > span::after.
